# How to clear password field after failed login?

Tags: django, django-login

I'm using django.contrib.auth.views.login to log in users. When login is failed, the user and password fields get posted back to the form.

What's the proper way to clean those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass [render_value=False](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput) when you create your password field's PasswordInput widget.

```
class YourAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```